# How to find bounds of integral of a C.D.F?

Tags: probability-distributions, bounds-of-integration

Suppose f(x,y) = {1/2 for 0<=x<=2 and 0<= y <= 1} 
and 0 otherwise.

Find Pr(X>=Y). So [everything to the right of x = y is where to integrate on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BymLV.png)
I believe you can find the bounds two ways: 
1. Integrate on x first then on y. $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{2}1/2 \,dx\,dy$$ and consequently the answer is 3/4.

2. Integrate on y first then on x. To me the bounds are intuitively supposed to be: $$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{o}^{x}1/2 \,dy\,dx$$

But that is not correct because the answer is 3/4.

Can someone explain how the to derive the bounds for the second method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the integral, since from $0 \le x \le 1$, $y$ goes between $0$ and $x$, but for $1 \le x \le 2$, $y$ goes between $0$ and $1$.

So the correct integral should be 
$$\int_0^1{\int_0^x{1/2 dy dx}} + \int_1^2{\int_0^1{1/2 dy dx}}$$
$$= 1/4+1/2 = 3/4$$

Comment: A much simpler way of integrating is to use the fact that $f(x,y)$ is constant, and just calculate the area where $X \ge Y$ and multiply by the value of $f$ (i.e., $1/2$)